# Update Vaadin Progressbar with push asynchronously

Tags: spring, websocket, push, vaadin8

I have a question when calculating the hash of files eg: md5, sha1, sha256 setting the progress in the progressBar through the asynchronous process

Thanks to **Alejandro Duarte** who shows a very practical example

https://github.com/newUserRepo/testbar/blob/issueBar/vaadin-upload/src/main/java/com/example/vaadinupload/ProcessingService.java#L44

the only way I can get it to work is that in method line 75, I put 4 milliseconds to process the task and the bar is updated, but it is too slow.

Yes, I do not sleep the Thread the application does not do the push correctly, and the changes are not reflected correctly to the client.

Another way that actually **worked** was with the Runnable interface and execute the heavy task in the run() method

```
@Override
public void run() {
    calcularHash();
}

public void calcularHash() {

    System.out.println("Path tmp archivo: " + 
        tmpPath.toFile().getAbsolutePath());

    for(int f=0; f<hashType.size(); f++) {
        try (InputStream bis = new 
                  BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(tmpPath))) {
            t.initTime();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            MessageDigest messageDigest = 
             MessageDigest.getInstance(hashType.get(f));
            int dataRead = 0;
            long largo = tmpPath.toFile().length();
            Long acum = 0L;
            while ((dataRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                messageDigest.update(buffer, 0, dataRead);
                acum += dataRead;
                Float per = ((float) acum / largo);
                bar.setValue(per);
                System.out.println(per * 100);
                //textFieldPercent.setValue(Types.formatPercentaje(per * 
           100));
            }
            final byte[] bytesDigest = messageDigest.digest();
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int c = 0; c < bytesDigest.length; c++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((bytesDigest[c] & 0xFF) + 0x100, 
               16).substring(1));
            }
            final String hashObtenido = sb.toString();
            t.finishTime();
            final String totalTime = t.getFinalTimeSec() + "seg " + 
                 t.getFinalTimeMs() + "ms";
            final String large = Types.getLargeFileFormat(largo);
            System.out.println(hashObtenido);
            ui.access(() -> {
                checksumTransactions.initData(messageDigest.getAlgorithm(), 
                                            sb.toString(),large, totalTime);
            });

           //Files.delete(tmpPath); //fixme borrar desde el grid o UI
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In the present picture I use a simple public void run () and the Progressbar is updated well

[image]

but we know that the application may have memory leaks and is not a good practice, the ideal would be to know how to execute that Background thread

I still do not know the best way to achieve this :$

Comment: What you may have [missed from Alejandro's example](https://github.com/newUserRepo/testbar/blob/issueBar/vaadin-upload/src/main/java/com/example/vaadinupload/VaadinUI.java#L96) and the [vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html#advanced.push.running) is the part about _accessing the UI from a background thread: mainly `access(() -> progressBar.setValue(percentage));`. [Here's one more tutorial](https://vaadin.com/blog/community-answer-processing-a-file-in-a-background-thread) from him regarding background file processing

Comment: Hi @Morfic well if that links you passed me already knew it thanks, I even base myself on it, to read the files hash asynchronously, but it does not work correctly the bar does not update, chrome notifies that you must close the tab, with a simple pdf of 33mg, not even the progressBar is updated correctly, it is strange, the only way is as mentioned above, with a simple public void run is that it works for me the example of alejandro has the access(()->bar.setValue(value))  in the UI class

Comment: @RubénEspinoza if you are not in the UI class when wanting to update the UI, you can use `UI.getCurrent().access(...);` or if that doesn't work, save the ui in a field in the constructor: `ui = UI.getCurrent();` so you can later call `ui.access(...);`

Comment: @Cashbee Hi, thanks for the help, right, if you look at the code and use the MyUI reference, I already think that another way to do this but with CompletableFuture<> and it works perfectly too, but with the example of alejandro, I can not set with the progressBar inside ui.access (() ->) because I block in the UI