# How to dismiss Vaadin 8 confirmation dialog while performing lengthy operation

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I have Vaadin 8 confirmation code there it performs a long lasting task. I would like to dismiss the dialog and show a progress bar:-

```
        ConfirmDialog.show(UI.getCurrent(), "Dynamic Report warning caption",
                "More than " +rows+ " rows in this table. It will take long time to generate this report.\nDo you still want to continue? ",
                SalkkuTM.getI18N("PortfolioManagementMenuBar.deleteData.confirmDialog.yes.caption"),
                SalkkuTM.getI18N("PortfolioManagementMenuBar.deleteData.confirmDialog.no.caption"), new ConfirmDialog.Listener() {
                    public void onClose(ConfirmDialog dialog) {
                        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
                        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
                        if (dialog.isConfirmed()) {
                            layout.addComponent(bar);
                            // this method does a long lasting task.
                            dynamicReportParameterGenerator();
                            bar.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

[image]

I would like to dismiss this dialog as soon as user select yes. And I would like to show an Indeterminate progress bar. I couldn't manage it. How to do it? Please let me know how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is FAQ stuff, you need to use [Server Push](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html) and update progress bar in background thread. There is a blog post and video about it here

https://vaadin.com/blog/community-answer-processing-a-file-in-a-background-thread

There is a good discussion about the topic here too

[Update Vaadin Progressbar with push asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937266/update-vaadin-progressbar-with-push-asynchronously)

> And I would like to show an Indeterminate progress bar.

This means that you can simplify things a little. If you do not want to update progress bar during the operation, you just need to put progress bar in UI in Indeterminate mode and once complete, update the UI again.