# Vaadin disable button during an action

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

How can I acheive this in Vaadin.

```
// inside myButton click event
myButton.setEnabled(false);
doMyActionThatTakeSomeTime();
myButton.setEnabled(true);
```

Inside the event, the button is never disabled because the UI is not refresh.

What would be the best practice to do this in Vaadin 11 (or 10) ?

- force view to refresh ? (how?)
- put my action inside a Thread ? (how ?)

Edit SOLUTION - *How to make it work with Thread*

So far, example with Thread (working):

```
@Push 
@Route(value = "secured")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout

[ ... ]

// inside click event
UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
new Thread(() -> {       
    ui.access(() -> {
      goButton.setEnabled(false);
      ui.push();
    });

    doMyActionThatTakeSomeTime();

    ui.access(() -> {
      goButton.setEnabled(true);
      ui.push();
    });
}).start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the "Asynchronous updates" chapter in the docs explains what you want: https://vaadin.com/docs/v11/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html . Basically: run `doMyActionThatTakeSomeTime()` in a separate background thread, then re-enable the button once the thread completes and Server Push will make sure the UI state is correctly updated.

This is frequently asked topic, there is also another answer here: [How to dismiss Vaadin 8 confirmation dialog while performing lengthy operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999262/how-to-dismiss-vaadin-8-confirmation-dialog-while-performing-lengthy-operation/51000244#51000244) Doing asynchronous updates work in Vaadin 8 and Vaadin 10+ in similar manner.

Comment: There is still a problem with this solution. I loose the "pending bar" that automatically display on top of page to warn that an operation is pending. How can I have it display when the thread is running ?

Answer (score 2):

In Vaadin 8, there’s a [`Button::setDisableOnClick()`](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/ui/Button.html#setDisableOnClick-boolean-) method for this exact purpose.

That should probably be reintroduced in the newer versions as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's a common need, It should be easy to implement.

Comment: Feature requested on the Vaadin Button Flow project, [GitHub issue # 27](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-button-flow/issues/27).

Answer (score 0):

For me the simplest way is this:

```
    Button btnAction = new Button("Action");
    btnAction.setDisableOnClick(true);
    btnAction.addClickListener(e -> {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 900000; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } finally {
            btnAction.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

A better way of doing it:

```
UI ui = UI.getCurrent();    
ui.access( () -> { 
    // disable button
    goButton.setEnabled(false);
    ui.push();

    doMyActionThatTakeSomeTime();

    // enable
    goButton.setEnabled(true);
    ui.push();
    });
```

Comment: Actually what you propose is not good solution. You have the long operation doMyActionThatTakeSomeTime(); within access() and that is not good. This will cause problems with blocked threads. Operations run within access() should be limited to atomic UI updates only.

Comment: I thoug it was better, because I get the 'pending bar' display automatically also. Which I don't get in the other solution (with Thread). Does it cause problem with Vaadin engine itself ?

Comment: In this kind of async tasks you should not depend on 'pending bar' of the framework. It is shown during lengthy wait operations, e.g. when UI is loading data from server. In your case it is showing up, since you have locked UI. This is a wrong way. If your operation is so long that progress indication is needed, instead you should use some UI component to show the progress and update that periodically in access(), e.g. https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-progress-bar